# Determine to which task a resource is allocated on a particular day

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

Using a shared resource pool for several project plans (each plan is contained in a separate file), what is the simplest way of working out to which task a given resource is allocated on a particular day?

For example, assume you are wondering why a particular (high-priority) task is not planned to start when you think it should.  One approach would be to show the Resource Usage view, scroll over to the day you think the task in question should start and notice that the resource assigned to that task is, indeed, fully allocated for the day.

At that point, it would be convenient to have a context menu entry for a cell in the Resource Usage view enabling navigation to the specific task (within a particular plan) representing the selected resource usage.  Since no such CME exists, I am wondering how to accomplish the goal of determining to which task a given resource is allocated on a particular day.

Comment: I think you have already answered your own question. The Resource Usage view shows the tasks the resource is assigned to, in a particular day (note that you will need to search the cells where there is assigned work for that day). This view, however, shows the task name only; you might need to add the “Project” column in the left table of the Resource Usage view, in order to know which particular project the task belongs to.

Comment: I found a good tutorial on sharing resources between different projects, where you can see is the resource is available to be used on a task. Hope this help you.
https://youtu.be/6f23OE8lTr8

Answer (score -1):

Great question! Navigating resource allocations across multiple project plans can indeed be challenging. While there isn't a direct context menu entry for such a task in Resource Usage view, one workaround is to leverage the 'Task Usage' view. Here, you can filter tasks by the specific resource and date, providing a detailed breakdown of allocations. Additionally, custom filters or resource reports can offer insights into resource allocation specifics.

Answer (score -2):

To determine to which task a given resource is allocated on a particular day when using a shared resource pool for several project plans, you can follow these steps:

1. Consolidate the project plans: Merge all the separate project plan files into a single master file or create a centralized database that contains the relevant information from each plan. This consolidation will allow you to have a comprehensive view of all the tasks and their corresponding allocations.
2. Identify the resource pool: In the consolidated project plan or database, identify the resource pool that includes all the resources available for allocation. Ensure that each resource is uniquely identified.
3. Locate the desired day: Navigate to the specific day you want to analyze or determine the task allocation for the resource.
4. Search for the resource: Locate the desired resource within the resource pool or database. Use the unique identifier associated with the resource to find it easily.
5. Analyze task allocations: Once you have found the resource, review the task allocations associated with that resource on the selected day. Look for any tasks assigned to the resource and note down their details, such as task names, start and end dates, and any other relevant information.

By following these steps, you can determine to which task a given resource is allocated on a particular day, even when working with a shared resource pool and separate project plan files.

Comment: This is extremely generic. The question is tagged with MS-Project, so please improve your answer with sufficient detail to implement the steps you're recommending *in Microsoft Project* rather than in generalities.